# Calculate Net AND overlapping Hours from date range using SQL Oracle 11GR2

Tags: sql, oracle, overlapping

I am trying to calculate Net Hours per day for given employee & a project.
An Employee cannot work more than 24 hours in a day. Hence, Need to calculate Net Hrs in  a day as well as overlapping Hours.
I have a partial solution designed but this doesn't work when end date-time of a task is same on a given date. I need help with resolving calculating Net Hours, Overlapping Hours for a given date.

```
SELECT
    person_id,
    start_time,
    end_time,
    project_id,
    mandatory_work,
    round((end_time - start_time) * 24, 2)         hours,
    round((end_time - start_time) * 24 - 
greatest((end_time - greatest(start_time, nvl(LAG(end_time)
OVER(PARTITION BY person_id, mandatory_work 
ORDER BY mandatory_work DESC, start_time ASC, end_time DESC),start_time))) * 24,0),2)                                      overlap_hrs,
    
round(greatest((end_time - greatest(start_time, nvl(LAG(end_time) 
OVER(PARTITION BY person_id, mandatory_work ORDER BY mandatory_work DESC, start_time ASC, end_time DESC),start_time))) * 24,0),2) 
net_hrs

FROM
    mytable
ORDER BY
    person_id,
    mandatory_work DESC,
    start_time ASC,
    end_time DESC;
```

Table Definition as follows

```
CREATE TABLE "MYTABLE" 
   (    "PERSON_ID" NUMBER, 
    "EVENT_DATE" CHAR(9), 
    "START_TIME" DATE, 
    "END_TIME" DATE, 
    "PROJECT_ID" VARCHAR2(9), 
    "MANDATORY_WORK" CHAR(1)
   )
REM INSERTING into MYTABLE
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (1111,'01-JUN-21',to_date('01-06-2021 18:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('02-06-2021 08:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'AAA','Y');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (1111,'02-JUN-21',to_date('02-06-2021 03:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('02-06-2021 04:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'BBB','Y');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (1111,'02-JUN-21',to_date('02-06-2021 06:16:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('02-06-2021 07:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'CCC','Y');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (1111,'03-JUN-21',to_date('02-06-2021 10:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('02-06-2021 10:15:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DDD','Y');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (1111,'03-JUN-21',to_date('02-06-2021 10:30:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('02-06-2021 11:15:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'EEE','Y');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (1111,'03-JUN-21',to_date('03-06-2021 11:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('03-06-2021 15:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'AAA','Y');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (1111,'01-JUN-21',to_date('01-06-2021 17:59:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('02-06-2021 08:01:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'AAA','N');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (1111,'02-JUN-21',to_date('02-06-2021 03:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('02-06-2021 04:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'BBB','Y');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (2222,'02-JUN-21',to_date('02-06-2021 18:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('03-06-2021 08:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'AAA','Y');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (2222,'03-JUN-21',to_date('03-06-2021 01:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('03-06-2021 10:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'BBB','Y');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (2222,'03-JUN-21',to_date('03-06-2021 01:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('03-06-2021 10:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'CCC','Y');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (2222,'02-JUN-21',to_date('02-06-2021 17:59:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('03-06-2021 07:49:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'AAA','N');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (1111,'02-JUN-21',to_date('02-06-2021 05:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('02-06-2021 07:15:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'CCC','N');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (1111,'02-JUN-21',to_date('02-06-2021 03:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('02-06-2021 04:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'BBB','Y');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (1111,'02-JUN-21',to_date('02-06-2021 05:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('02-06-2021 07:15:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'CCC','N');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (1111,'02-JUN-21',to_date('02-06-2021 03:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('02-06-2021 04:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'BBB','Y');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (3333,'03-Jun-21',to_date('03-06-2021 14:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('03-06-2021 21:59:59','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'TESTING','Y');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (3333,'03-Jun-21',to_date('03-06-2021 14:37:46','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('03-06-2021 14:42:46','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'TESTING','Y');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (3333,'03-Jun-21',to_date('03-06-2021 15:35:08','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('03-06-2021 21:59:59','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'TESTING','Y');
Insert into MYTABLE (PERSON_ID,EVENT_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,PROJECT_ID,MANDATORY_WORK) values (3333,'03-Jun-21',to_date('03-06-2021 18:08:46','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('03-06-2021 18:13:46','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'TESTING','Y');
```

Desired output is as follows. We should be seeing "0" instead of 6.41 on second row for net_hrs.
[image]

Comment: PLease provide the desired output for the sample data

Comment: Query output is desired output format.. or you can add 3 columns , total_hrs, overlap_hrs and net_hrs.

Comment: Not a format, but the data you want to see

Comment: Why are you partitioning by `MANDITORY_WORK`? Do you allow overlap when somework is manditory and some isn't?

Comment: No we can remove that, but I am not sure if that resolves this issue.. thought

Comment: can you use PL/SQL ? or you need to solve this with SELECT only ?

Comment: No preferences for SQL only. PL/SQL can do as log as it solves the problem..